# Fragment shader reading value in uniform array in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, uniform, glsles

I've got a fragment shader that downsamples the colors to 4 different colors.
To do this, I compute an index based on the color that varies from 0 to 3.
I then lookup the value of the final color in an uniform array of vec4:

The declaration of the array:

```
uniform vec4 u_colors[4];
```

The lookup:

```
gl_FragColor = u_colors[int(index)];
```

This works well on some devices, but on some devices (such on a Tegra 4) it seems I can't access an array with a variable, and the output is garbage. The only work-around that I found is this:

```
index = floor(index);
if (index < 2.0) {
  if (index == 0.0) {
    gl_FragColor = u_colors[0];
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = u_colors[1];
  }
} else {
  if (index == 2.0) {
    gl_FragColor = u_colors[2];
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = u_colors[3];
  }
}
```

This works, and surprisingly the performance is still pretty good, but it's obviously not ideal.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the GPU driver/compiler? What efficient alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GLSL ES 1.00` for `OpenGL ES 2.0` [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) has this line:

> **Uniforms (excluding samplers)**
>
> In the vertex shader, support for all forms of array indexing is
> mandated. In the fragment shader, support for indexing is only
> mandated for constant-index-expressions.

Most drivers implement this functionality in fragment shaders, but it's not required so Tegra 4 has all rights to refuse to accept your code.